# Array of ints and the keyword final. [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, int, final

The below code compiles in Java.

```
public class App{
  public static void main(String args[]){   
    final int[]array = {1,2,3};
    array[2] = 6; //Why can this value be changed if it is final.
  }
}
```

Why when making an array of ints "final", does it not make the values case constant. The array values can still be changed above as seen "array[2]=6".

What is the point of the keyword final being used on an array of ints?
Is there any way to make this array of ints case constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. final means your reference is final, not the value.